# Bootstrap for sass not resizing icons

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-3.2, sass, less

I'm using compass and bootstrap for sass on a project. Everything works well. The only thing I can't figure out is how to resize the icon glyphs.

For example, when bootstrap is running on its default less configuration I can simply increase the icon size by adding a `font-size` css  method to the parent element. It was working well, but when I switched to bootstrap for sass the icon lost its color and its font-size.

Any ideas what could have gone wrong? Boostrap is imported properly in my `application.css.sass` file.

```
@import jquery.ui.all
@import variables.css.scss
@import bootstrap
@import sass-rules.css.scss
@import fonts.css.scss
@import general.css.scss
@import containers.css.scss
@import jquery.Jcrop.min
@import header.css.scss
@import side_bar.css.scss
@import modal.css.scss
@import home.css.scss
@import users.css.scss
@import items.css.scss
@import messages.css.scss
@import notifications.css.scss
@import me.css.scss
@import friends.css.scss
@import discover.css.scss
```

**Update**

Gemfile Assets

```
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails', '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'


  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  gem 'therubyracer', :platform => :ruby
  gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails'
  gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 2.1.0.0'

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'

end
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
gem 'compass'
```

Using [this](https://github.com/thomas-mcdonald/bootstrap-sass) bootstrap for sass gem. I'm not using any mixins for the icons.

Comment: Have you looked at the mixins in question?  Which compilation are you using (there is more than one project that's converted the Twitter Bootstrap into Sass)?

Comment: @cimmanon, just updated. Thanks

Comment: You still have not linked to the Bootstrap project you're referring to.

Comment: @cimmanon, Sorry.. Updated again...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not seeing anything in that project suggests it is using something like [FontAwesome](http://fortawesome.github.com/Font-Awesome/).  The only icons I see are from a [sprite map](https://github.com/thomas-mcdonald/bootstrap-sass/blob/master/vendor/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/_sprites.scss), and obviously those are not resizable.  FontAwesome does provide a Sass file with all of the icons in it:

https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/blob/master/sass/font-awesome.scss

Comment: Makes sense. At the moment I'm getting this error `@import "compass/css3/font-face";`. Is there a command I should run to set this up? I just downloaded it and put the `.ttf` file in my fonts and the `.scss` file in my stylesheets folder.

Comment: I've never used Compass, but you will need to get it if you want to use the file as is (you can find Compass here:  http://compass-style.org/).  I am using FontAwesome in my current project and simply wrote my own version of that file where I only generate classes for only the glyphs I am using.

Comment: I got the error because the compass gem was wrong. I changed it and now I'm good, but its not loading the glyphs properly now - I have squares on the page haha. I'm sure I can fix that now. Thanks for your help!